# Android studio does not show strings preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio on Mac OS X and I'm not able to see the hard-coded strings values in the editor as well as I cannot see drawables preview. Anyway, I can see colour preview in the xml file. Is there any option that I need to turn on?

I know that this may be due to a bug, but they've strongly publicized this feature so IMHO it works!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The option "Android String References" must be checked under Settings > Editor > Code Folding, but it is checked by default. For me, it doesn't seem to do the string preview automatically. I have to right click anywhere in some code like `getString(R.string.mystring)` then go to Folding > Collapse. Or, you can just hit Ctrl + '-' to collapse it as well. This might be the intended behavior or a bug. It seems like they implied it was automatic in the keynote speech, but maybe it's not.

As far as the drawables preview goes, I think it only works for drawables with only one resource instance. So if you have an icon.png in more than one drawable folder (eg. drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi), then you won't get the preview. At least, that's how it worked for me. I only saw the preview when I tried it with an icon that was in just one drawable folder.

Comment: well after restart it shows me the right value for strings, but drawables are still not shown, even if they are only in the `drawable` folder.. This is not a problem, it's a preview and it's normal to have many bugs! I'm sure they will fix it soon!

Answer (score 23):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> on Mac OS X) when your cursor is on `getString` or the preview word, then the string is switched.

Comment: For those who doesn't now what is period button - i didn't for example, - it is a dot button [.], second to the right after [M] button. In upper registry it is a greater then sign [>].

Answer (score 1):

Now you should use keyboard shortcut Command + '-' or Command + '.' in android studio to show strings preview.